# install stack N220 of processmaker 3.2.3

Tags: php, nginx, processmaker

I am trying install stack N220 : https://wiki.processmaker.com/3.2/Stack_220
but in the last step error occurred:

> An error occurred.
>
> Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable. Please
>   try again later.
>
> If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should
>   check the error log for details.
>
> Faithfully yours, nginx.

**Error log:**

> connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm/processmaker.sock the file does not
>   exist.

Comment: are you sure you are running that stack? you should not be getting an error about nginx as processmaker 3 runs on apache.

Comment: as you can see, N330 stack is based on nginx @EthanPresberg :  https://wiki.processmaker.com/3.2/Stack_N220

Comment: ahh ok.. the original link you posted was to the apache version. Is nginx a requirement for you? if not i'd try with apache.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of unconfig php-fpm , and enable it on start up after solve this problem another error occurred!!

```
file not found
```

maybe because of bad configuration!

```
Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client...
```